# Displaying custom error message but will stay in the page in yii2 advance

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii-components

I need to display my custom error message when submit button was hit if the error was caught, but it should be displayed on the page where the error was encountered.

I tried using setFlash but it caused an error, addError as well. Can someone please help me. Thank you!!

Comment: add your code and a little more explaination. you want the page to be reloaded after submit and display the error or not. you are using `flash` messages which wont appear until you reload or redirect, you should use client validation but need to add the relevant code first

Comment: No code, just need help.. The easiest way to display my custom error message when error was found after hitting submit button.

Comment: do mark the answer as correct if it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to display error messages after submit is to use `<?php $form->errorSummary($model)?>` just after you have declared the form.

```
<?php    
$form=ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'my-form']);
$form->errorSummary($model);    
ActiveForm::end();
?>
```

you action should look like this I assume you have a `actionCreate` with a view name `create` and `Product` model.

```
public function actioncreate(){
    $model=new Product();
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()){
       return $this->redirect(['view','id'=>$model->id]);
    }
    return $this->render('create',['model'=>$model]);
}
```